# How to compute the partial sums $\sum_{k=0}^n (k+1)z^k$ without any differentiation/integration

Tags: calculus, summation

One can compute the series if $|z|<1$ which was done here [How to derive the limits of $\sum_{k=0}^\infty k q^k$ and $\sum_{k=0}^\infty k^2 q^k$ for $|q| < 1$ without using differentiation/integration?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75129/how-to-derive-the-limits-of-sum-k-0-infty-k-qk-and-sum-k-0-infty-k2).
Unfortunately, the shifting trick does not work for the partial sums.

I want to observe how the sum $\sum_{k=0}^n (k+1)z^k$ for $z\neq 1$ can be evaluated without any differentiation/integration. Obviously one can first
split the sum up
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^n (k+1)z^k=\sum_{k=0}^n kz^k + \sum_{k=0}^n z^k = \sum_{k=0}^n kz^k+ \frac{1-z^{n+1}}{1-z}.
\end{align}
How can I evaluate the first sum without any differentation/integration?

Comment: Shifting trick should work, shift the sum and compare that with original.

Answer (score 3):

Let $$S := \sum_{k=0}^n kz^k$$
Then, $$zS = \sum_{k=0}^n kz^{k+1} = \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} (k-1)z^k$$
Subtracting, we have
$$S(1-z) = \sum_{k=0}^n kz^k - \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} (k-1)z^k = -nz^{n+1} + \sum_{k=1}^n z^k$$
giving
$$S = \frac{-nz^{n+1} + \sum_{k=1}^n z^k}{1-z}$$
which you can further simplify since $\sum_{k=1}^n z^k$ is just a (finite) geometric sum.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I made a mistake, but this should be the way:
$$\sum_{k=0}^n(k+1)z^k=\sum_{k=0}^n\sum_{s=0}^kz^k=\sum_{0\leq s\leq k\leq n}z^k=\sum_{s=0}^{n}\sum_{k=s}^nz^k=\sum_{s=0}^nz^s\sum_{k=0}^{n-s}z^k=$$
$$=\sum_{s=0}^nz^s\frac{1-z^{n-s+1}}{1-z}=\frac{1}{1-z}\sum_{s=0}^n\left[z^s-z^{n+1}\right]=\frac{-(n+1)z^{n+1}}{1-z}+\frac{1}{1-z}\sum_{s=0}^nz^s=$$
$$=\frac{-(n+1)z^{n+1}}{1-z}+\frac{1-z^{n+1}}{(1-z)^2}=\frac{1-z^{n+1}}{(1-z)^2}-(n+1)\frac{z^{n+1}-z^{n+2}}{(1-z)^2}=$$
$$=\frac{1-(n+2)z^{n+1}+(n+1)z^{n+2}}{(1-z)^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

We can apply the formula:
$$\sum_{k=0}^nb_k\left [\sum_{l=0}^{k}a_l\right]=\sum_{l=0}^{n}a_l\left [\sum_{k=l}^{n}b_k\right]$$ Let $a_l=1$ and $b_k=z^k.$ Then
$$\sum_{k=0}^n(k+1)z^k=\sum_{l=0}^{n} \left [\sum_{k=l}^{n}z^k\right]\\ =\sum_{l=0}^{n}{z^{n+1}-z^{l}\over z-1}= (n+1){z^{n+1}\over z-1}-{z^{n+1}-1\over (z-1)^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $S_n = 1 + 2x + 3x^2 + \ldots + (n+1)x^n$.

We have
\begin{array}{r}
S_n &=& 1 &+& 2x &+& 3x^2 &+& 4x^3 &+& 5x^4 &+&\ldots &+&(n+1)x^n\\
xS_n &=&  && 1x &+& 2x^2 &+& 3x^3 &+& 4x^4 &+&\ldots &+&nx^n&+&(n+1)x^{n+1}\\
x^2S_n &=&  &&  && 1x^2 &+& 2x^3 &+& 3x^4 &+&\ldots &+&(n-1)x^n&+&nx^{n+1}&+&(n+1)x^{n+2}\\
\end{array}

Take a look at the coefficients of $x^k$, $k =1,2,\ldots,n;$ in each row: they follow the pattern $k+1$, $k$, $k-1$ which is arithmetic progression, so we know that the middle is arithmetic average of the other two, i.e. $2k = (k+1)+(k-1)$, or $(k+1)-2k+(k-1) = 0$. This tells us that $$S_n-2xS_n+x^2S_n = 1-(n+2)x^{n+1}+(n+1)x^{n+2}$$
or $$S_n = \frac 1{(1-x)^2}-\frac {(n+2)x^{n+1}-(n+1)x^{n+2}}{(1-x)^2}.$$

---

To motivate looking at $x^2S_n$ in the first place, you might observe from $S_n$ and $xS_n$ that you need to do $S_n-2xS_n$ to cancel out coefficients of $x$, but then you notice no other coefficients cancel, so by bringing in $x^2S_n$ you are hoping you might get the desired cancelation, which in fact you do.

Another approach, which I think is covered by other answers, is to just multiply the expression by $1-x$ since it works well for the case $1+x+x^2+\ldots$. Then you would get something familiar (as shown in other answers) and realize you need to multiply by $1-x$ again. This approach generalizes well if you wished to differentiate geometric series twice or more and derive the corresponding result without differentiation: you just multiply by $(1-x)^k$, where $k$ is the number of times you differentiate and then obtain the result by induction.